# How to I repair moulding damaged by Blue Scotch tape?

Tags: trim, laminate

I put blue scotch tape on my laminate moulding to protect it when I was painting the trim.  I wasn't able to paint the room all in one weekend, and as things go, it took a few weekends to finish the job.  When I removed the tape it pulled off the laminate covering.

I'd rather not replace the moulding.  Is there a good way to repair this?

[image: Damaged Moulding. That is not paint. The laminate was actually torn off.]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet then would to get an artist brush and acrylic paint from an art supply or craft store. That can be blended to get the color you need to touch it in, though replacing it would be my choice to do. All told it would take less time, and about the same cost, if you have the cutting tools.

Comment: It may seem simpler to repair it, but to repair it well enough to hide it is very time consuming, if not impossible, in my experience. I would recommend you give yourself some time, then when you're ready, replace it. Down the road, if you're like me, you'll always notice it if you repair it; but, you will always be proud if you replace it. Just my opinion though.

Comment: Its the baby room and this happened in a few spots.  I'd like it to look really nice.  I'll go with replace.

Answer (score 1):

The area might be too big for this to work well, but you can try a putty pencil typically used for fixing small defects in floors.  They come in a variety of colors.

[image: Putty Pencil]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/PA10133C_4.jpg))</sub>